# tmux error on debian

Tags: tmux

I install tmux via apt-get. When I type `tmux`, it acts like first `$ clear` and then open another bash, I can not see any render borders as usual nor to split or create any windows or panes. Then I type `tmux ls`, it shows `0: 1 windows (created Fri Oct  2 19:26:26 2015) [193x44] (attached)`.

BTW, I'm using xshell to ssh login that machine.

Comment: What happens if you `tmux a` after the `tmux`?

Comment: @tripflag `sessions should be nested with care, unset $TMUX to force`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so tmux *did* start and you are inside the session... The only option I can think of is that your installation comes with non-standard settings that hide the status bar and uses another prefix key for commands. Try putting the following in `~/.tmux.conf` and see if things work better after a `killall -9 tmux`:

```
set -g pane-active-border-style fg=green
set -g pane-border-style default
set -g prefix C-b
set -g status on
set -g status-bg green
set -g status-left "#(cat /proc/loadavg)"
```

Comment: One more error is that tmux can't preserve the current working directory when creating new pane or window. I add these commands in the conf but still not working:`bind '"' split-window -c "#{pane_current_path}"
bind % split-window -h -c "#{pane_current_path}"
bind c new-window -c "#{pane_current_path}"`